# Extract values from different columns based on ID

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My data set contains ID and many columns that have ID on their name.

```
data = data.frame(ID = rep(1:3,2),
col1 = 1:6,
col2 = 7:12,
col3 = 13:18)

print(data)
```

I'm trying to make a variable based on its ID from different columns.

```
data$new = c(1, 8, 15, 4, 11, 18)
```

I tried it with dplyr using `get(paste0())`, but it calls the entire vector, not the specific element.

```
data <- data %>% mutate(new = get(paste0("col",ID)))
```

I also tried sapply but it again gives the vector not the element

```
data$new <- sapply(data$ID, function(x) get(paste0("col",ID),data)
```

How can I pick up the element from different columns by its ID?

Comment: try `rowwise()`  i.e. `data %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(new = get(paste0("col",ID)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your original approach with `rowwise()` if you like
i.e.

```
data %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(new = get(paste0("col",ID)))
```

You could also do something like:

```
data$new <- apply(data, 1, \(x) x[x[1]+1])
```

the above only works if you **only** have ID and the `col<num>` columns, and they are in order. If that is not the case you could do this:

```
cols = sort(grep("col",names(data),value=T))
data$new <- apply(data[,c("ID", cols)], 1, \(x) x[x[1]+1])
```

And, while I wouldn't necessarily recommend it for your current situation, often its easier to work on some issues like this when the data are in long format:

```
bind_cols(
  select(data, ID, starts_with("col")),
  tidyr::pivot_longer(data,-ID,names_prefix = "col") %>% filter(name==ID) %>% select(new=value)
)
```

All the above provide the same result

Answer (score 0):

You can create row number in your dataframe to mimick the behaviour of `rowwise`.

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(rid = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(new = get(paste0("col", ID)), .by = rid) %>% 
  select(-rid)
```

With your `sapply` approach, I think you don't need to `get` the column, just `paste` it for direct indexing:

```
data$new <- sapply(1:nrow(data), \(x) data[x, paste0("col", data[x, "ID"])])
```

Both give the same output:

```r
  ID col1 col2 col3 new
1  1    1    7   13   1
2  2    2    8   14   8
3  3    3    9   15  15
4  1    4   10   16   4
5  2    5   11   17  11
6  3    6   12   18  18
```